# Set attribute of all fields in Django ModelForm in init method

Tags: python, django, forms, attributes, init

I have a Django ModelForm where I set certain form attributes in the form `__init__()` method.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['datecreated', 'datemodified']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'class1'
        self.fields['field2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'class1'
        self.fields['field3'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'class1'
        # override Google Chrome field error issues making form unfocusable
        self.fields['field1'].required = False
        self.fields['field2'].required = False
        self.fields['field3'].required = False
```

Is there away to set attributes of **all fields included in the form** without writing self.fields for each one individually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`self.fields` is a normal dict, you can just iterate over its values:

```
for field in self.fields.values():
    field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'class1'
    field.required = False
```