# How to change the width of a drop-down field in a django form using widget attributes not css

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I am trying to make all of the fields in my Django form have the same size to look tidy. I have text input, drop down and text area. I am creating the form using the `Ticket` model so I am not defining the form fields explicitly. I was able to resize the text input, but what is the attribute in a drop-down field that controls the width? Note that the choices in the drop-down are basically foreign keys from another table that are defined in the model.

```
class NewTicket(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Ticket

        fields = ('subject','business','project','description')

        widgets={
            'subject': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '20px'}),
            'business': forms.Select(attrs={'size': '20px'}) #this line does not work
            }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know you said no CSS but is this an option?

```
class NewTicket(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Ticket

        fields = ('subject','business','project','description')

        widgets={
            'subject': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width:20px'}),
            'business': forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width:20px'})
            }
```

Comment: it worked, do you know how I can apply this to all of the fields without mentioning one by one explicitly?

Comment: This is another question but you can either do that with CSS in your templates or dynamically change the widget with something like `form.fields['subject'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width:20px'})`

Comment: you are mentioning the field `subject` explicitly, I meant using something like `__all__`etc

Comment: That's an example, you can loop through your fields, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283636/set-attribute-of-all-fields-in-django-modelform-in-init-method) :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the widget attributes, eg. in the `__init__()` as

```
mystyle = {"style": "width:400px;", "size": 8, "rows": 8}
self.fields["something"].widget.attrs = mystyle
```

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs